# Drawing Android Gallery items from right to left

Tags: android, drawing, gallery

I want to use an Android Gallery but draw the items from right to left (the writing direction in Hebrew)
The Gallery items represent chapters in a book written in Hebrew, so that the item order is important

Android draws them in the opposite direction like this (the first item is chosen)
**1** 2 3 4 5

instead of this
5 4 3 2 **1**

I already tried overriding these methods in my Gallery class
(none of them changed the drawing order):

```
@Override
public int getChildDrawingOrder(int childCount, int i) {
    return getChildDrawingOrder(childCount, childCount - i+1)
}
```

I know from Debugging that the getChildDrawingOrder was visited
I tried a couple of variations of this, but non of them worked

I also tried

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.rotate(180, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

I'll be happy if anyone can help me with this
I can't get this right

Thank you Very Much
Oron

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feed the Gallery with images using an ImageAdapter class and load the images in reverse order e.g.

```
gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
Integer[] mImageIds = new Integer[] {                   
    R.drawable.chapter_5_image,
    R.drawable.chapter_4_image,
    R.drawable.chapter_3_image,             
    R.drawable.chapter_2_image,
    R.drawable.chapter_1_image};
    imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, mImageIds);
    gallery.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
```

The ImageAdapter class should extend android.widget.BaseAdapter - there are plent of example around showing how to implement an adapter of this type.

Also, set the initial selection in the gallery as follows:

```
gallery.setSelection(4, true);
```

This should position the gallery to show the Chapter 1 image.

Comment: This is the most obvious, simplest solution. No reason to go mucking about in the component code when you can alter the structure of your data.

Comment: Thank you @John J Smith this does work but it forces me to change other application code. I was hoping for a GUI side solution. my application shows bible books and chapters, and there are links that can lead you to an entirely different book. using this implementation I would have to change the link redirection code, so I was hoping for a solution to bypass that. Thanks again

Comment: Perhaps instead of just using an array of integers you could use an array of a class which encapsulates the image position number and any other details which could help generate the links dynamically. If you think this answered your question, remember to click the green tick to accept :)